# Logging single or, selected method's query in Spring JPA Data Rest API based repository

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot

I have seen the use of following to output native SQL queries in console in a Spring Boot project:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.type=trace
```

However these flood the console with ton of queries since everything gets logged.

How can I log only a selected repository Rest API based method i.e. which has `@Query` annotation with JPA query over it?

What methods are available and how is it possible to configure? I haven't found a single working approach.